# Installing android emulator for android-skd-tools

Tags: nativescript, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to setup android development environment without Android Studio on Windows system. I will be developing an application using nativescript so I followed their tutorial and was able to setup things as mentioned on their page([link](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win)). And tns doctor gives "No issues were detected".

*Note: I haven't used Chocolatey to manage the installation. I have manually installed the packages that were mentioned on the page.*

I created avd using:

```
avdmanager create avd -n nvDev -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -b google_apis/x86
```

which is also listed by(emulator is under 'tools' folder)

```
emulator -list-avds
--------------------------
nvDev
```

Now when I try to start emulator it is giving me error:

```
emulator.exe -avd nvDev
--------------------------
[3708]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch '..\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory
```

As emulator folder was not found I tried to install emulator using the sdkmanager but it gives me a warning:(sdkmanager is under tools/bin)

```
sdkmanager "emulator"
Warning: File C:\Users\CES_Arion\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
```

There was no "done" message. And even the emulator folder was not created alongside tools.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I feel so foolish now. The problem was I did not run the command prompt as an Admin so the files could not be created.